# Crop the android image

Tags: android

I want to develop a selfie app in which we need the crop

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
File file = new File(filePath);  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);  
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);
```

Answer (score 2):

For custom page you can use image cropping libraries. There are many of them, this is very handful library for advanced cropping

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop made by Yalantis team

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso it will be very easy for you.

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView);
```

Download the jar file and add it in your project lib
[click Here to download](http://square.github.io/picasso/)